# Pasar información al hacer clic de un contenedor a otro en angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Quisiera saber como realizar lo siguiente en typescript:

Tengo un div el cual me trae la información de un array, deseo que al hacer clic en cualquiera de los ítems de este contenedor me lo envíe a otro contenedor y automáticamente se quite del contenedor actual y viceversa.

Tengo el siguiente array **todo** y quiero que al hacer clic se envíe al array **done**

```
todo = ['Ítem 1', 'Ítem 2', 'Ítem 3'];

done = []
```

En el html tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Todo</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-1" *ngFor='let item of todo'>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Done</h2>
  <div class="contenedor-2" *ngFor="let item of done">{{item}}</div>  
</div>
```

Entonces si yo le doy clic a los ítems en el contenedor-1 que es de el array **todo** estos se deben pasar al contenedor-2, y si yo le doy clic a los ítems del contenedor-2 que es del array **done** se deben pasan al contenedor-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cada elemento de `todo` y `done` agrégale un evento `click` que ejecute una función que se encargue de mover datos de un arreglo a otro.

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <b>Todo</b>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let t of todo" (click)="moveTo(todo, done, t)">{{t}}</li>
    </ul>

    <b>Done</b>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let d of done" (click)="moveTo(done, todo, d)">{{d}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  todo = ["Ítem 1", "Ítem 2", "Ítem 3"];

  done = [];

  moveTo(from: string[], to: string[], item: string) {
    from.splice(from.indexOf(item),1);
    to.push(item);
  }
}
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ug645m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Funciona, gracias.